# Return different types from methods depending on some condition c#

Tags: c#, .net

all! I'm facing the following problem now. Consider a method which should create new list of, for example objects of type `Room` if there is some free space, or return a list objects of type `RoomConflict` otherwise, so the pseudo code would be the following:

```
public [some type] CreateRooms(){
if(there is some space){
   return new List<Room>(){new Room(), new Room()};
}
else{
  return new List<RoomConflict>(){new RoomConflict(), new RoomConflict()}
}}
```

How to create such method? Do I need to use `dynamic` type of `object`. Or maybe `KeyValuePair<List<Room>,List<RoomConflict>>` and pass null to not used param. What solution is better?

Comment: You can create a baseclass or an interface and return this.

Comment: Is `RoomConflict` inheriting from `Room`? Or are they of the same `interface` or inheriting from the same `base class`?

Comment: I'd take a look at the [abstract factory](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/designpatterns/4EJN020613-Abstract-Factory-Design-Pattern---C) design pattern.

Comment: I think Room and RoomConflict are entirely different classes. Just judging from the name, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: @ArkayCZ, Yeah, thay have not a lot in common, only 2 props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `Room` and `RoomConflict` both implement some common interface? In other words, can the caller cast the result as an `IRoom` and use the returned object without actually knowing whether it's a `Room` or a `RoomConflict`? If the answer is no, then the answer is not to try to do what you're doing.

When someone calls a method they shouldn't need to inspect the result to see what type it is. For example, you wouldn't want someone to call the method, get a result, and then check to see if the object returned is a `Room` or a `RoomConflict`. The point of strongly-typed programming is that you don't need to do that.

Without knowing too much about how these classes will be used, I would recommend just returning a list of available rooms if there are any, and having the method return an empty list if there are no available rooms. That way the method always returns a `List<Room>`, and if there are none then the list is just empty.

If a `RoomConflict` is a completely different object then perhaps whatever functionality deals with `RoomConflict` should be in a different method or different class. One of the best practices to learn is having each class maintain a single responsibility and not try to make one class or one method do unrelated things.

Comment: Yeah, I'm also thinking that this is not a very good approach, but you make it clearer:)

Answer (score 1):

If the code that's calling the method knows, what Class will be returned you could consider using generics. If not, you can either use a plain `Object` or create a wrapper class, that could hold both types, one of which would be `null`.

But I think the correct solution would be to have a condition in the code that's calling the method, checking the condition you have in the method, and calling a either a method that returns `RoomConfict` or one that returns `Room`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given context, I would suggest returning `null` when there is conflict instead of creating a `RoomConflict` class..

Then you could just have `null` checking then handle what needs to be handled

EDIT: just to demonstrate Scott's answer using `null` checking

```
    void BuildHouse()
    {
        List<Room> rooms = CreateRooms();
        foreach (Room room in rooms)
        {
            if(room != null)
            {
                //paint room
            }
            else
            {
                //expand lot
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need this because I'll display conflicting 'Rooms'

Comment: The one calling the `CreateRooms` can do that by `null` checking.

Comment: @IhorKorotenko see my edit. hopefully that could help

Answer (score 0):

your choice between `dynamic` type of `object` depends on caller of this method.

`dynamic` will bind the type at run time while `object` will do a compile time checking and boxing of return type to object type(Additional operation). In both cases caller has to evaluate the return type to cast the return type.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I typically handle situations like this is I create a response type that contains success, a value if successful, and a reason if it's not successful. So for your case it would look something like this:

```
public class RoomRequestResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public Room ResultValue { get; set }
    public RoomConflict FailureReason { get; set; }
}
```

So then your return type would be `IEnumerable<RoomRequestResult>` and each element of the resulting collection would be self describing.